# React Hooks "useState/useEffect/useCallback" are called conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please tell me where do I need to put the **list.length condition** to remove the **React Hooks are called conditionally error**? I tried to wrap it in useEffect, but in this case an empty list is returned at the first render. It is **important** that the list is returned at the first render in the same way as with the logic in the code below.

```
const List = ({ list }) => {
  if (list.length === 0) {
    return <div>LOADING...</div>;
  }

  const [localList, setLocalList] = useState(list);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList(localList);
  }, [localList]);

  const handleChange = useCallback((id) => {
    setLocalList((prevLocalList) =>
      prevLocalList.map((item, index) => {
        return index !== id ? item : { ...item, checked: !item.checked };
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {localList?.map((item, index) => (
        <MemoRow key={index} {...item} handleChange={handleChange} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendered result is returned at the end of the component, not at the beginning.  Make that first operation part of the overall `return` at the end:

```
return (
  list.length === 0 ?
    <div>LOADING...</div> :
    <>
      {localList?.map((item, index) => (
        <MemoRow key={index} {...item} handleChange={handleChange} />
      ))}
    </>
);
```

---

Additionally, there is a logical issue in your component.  When a parent component passes the `list` value, you are duplicating that in local state in this component.  If the parent component *changes* the value of `list`, this component will re-render but *will not update its local state*.

Given the term "LOADING..." in the UI, this implies that's exactly what's happening here.  So on a re-render, `list.length === 0` is now `false`, but `localList` *is still empty*.

As a "quick fix" you can just update `localList` any time `list` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLocalList(list);
}, [list, setLocalList]);
```

Of course, this will also over-write any local changes to `localList` if the parent component ever changes `list` again.  But since this is *duplicated state* then it's not really clear what should happen in that case anyway.  Perhaps you could only conditionally update it if `localList` is empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (localList.length === 0) {
    setLocalList(list);
  }
}, [list, setLocalList, localList]);
```

It's really up to you how you want to handle edge cases like that.  But ultimately you're going to need to update `localList` after `list` has changed if you want those changes to be reflected in your local state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David, but to be honest I already tried this one and nothing changes as well.
Here is the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/testovoe-zadanie-7jfdf6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @feelingreat: That example isn't producing the error described in the question.  So... problem solved?  What's the issue?

Comment: My bad then. I mean after adding this IF statement into the return - empty list is returned at the first render and because of that I can't see checkboxes list. And that is not how it should work. So, how can I fix that?

Comment: @feelingreat: The difference between `list` and `localList` is pretty suspect.  And what even is `setList`?  That's never defined in the code shown.  Is that producing a different error for you?  The use of the term "LOADING..." in the UI implies that something is being fetched asynchronously.  Is `list` being changed by a parent component?  If so, by the time it loads it's too late for this component.  The duplicated state of `localList` has already been set to an empty array and isn't being updated anywhere.

Comment: setList is a function that I cannot change in any way due to the conditions of the task. It just has to be there.

Comment: @feelingreat: Either way, if `list` is changing (and this component isn't destroyed/re-created by its parent but instead just re-rendering) then the rendering logic here is acting on the new `list` but still rendering the same `localList`.  Duplicating state requires you to keep that state manually synchronized.  You may need an additional `useEffect` which will call `setLocalList(list)` any time `list` changes, but more appropriately you probably shouldn't be duplicating state in the first place.